# Image cropping/resizing before sending to a server

Tags: image, resize, client-side, crop

I am searching for a solution that will allow a user to upload an image, crop the image, and then send the updated image to the server.

Basically, I would like to handle all the editing client side and only send the new, smaller, thumbnail to the server.

How can I do this? I have seen this is possible with Flash, but I am looking for alternative solutions.

Comment: Did you ever develop a solution for this? I'm currently seeking some sort of Javascript plugin I could use to crop an image before it gets sent to the server (I don't want to have to upload it and then crop it, I just want to crop it before it gets sent).

Answer (score 0):

Are you restricted to certain browsers?  Using HTML5, here is a [proof of concept](http://www.pandamatak.com/people/anand/blog/2010/11/clientside_image_crop_and_then.html) from Anand Venkataraman. Demo is [here](http://pandamatak.com/people/anand/test/crop/).

Comment: I am limited, all the way down to IE6.

Comment: I doubt you'll have many options, if any, to do it on the client side without flash or something similar.