# Uploading image part by part

Tags: php, image-processing

Is there a way to upload an image part by part via PHP ?  I mean we are virtually drawing a grid on that image and uploading our desired sell of the image .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try sending it in chunks via converting it into bytearray and reassembling them at other end

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to **upload** a specific part of the image, you should take a look at client side cropping:
[Image cropping/resizing before sending to a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492736/image-cropping-resizing-before-sending-to-a-server)

You could of course just select the desired region on the client-side, upload the whole image and then crop it with php libraries like [GD](http://php.net/manual/de/book.image.php) or [Imagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php)